# Is this what it looks like in the terminal on the client side when you are blocked out via fail2ban?

Tags: security, iptables, fail2ban

I am a new server admin. I just setup fail2ban on an ubuntu 12.04 VPS. I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial. Then I tried to login to the system via ssh from a friend's machine. It is showing "operation timed out." It seems like this means fail2ban is working -- but I want to double check to be certain. Is this what it looks like on the client side when fail2ban has blocked your IP? Your SSH login times out because fail2ban/iptables does not allow it to initiate on the server side?

```
$ ssh -p# user@IP
user@IP's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
user@IP's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
user@IP's password: 
^C
$ ssh -p# user@IP
ssh: connect to host IP port #: Operation timed out
$ ssh -p# user@IP
ssh: connect to host IP port #: Operation timed out
```

Comment: http://felipeferreira.net/?p=47. That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at this tutorial it states you'll see a timeout which is consistent with what you're seeing, titled: [Fail2ban - Rackspace Knowledge Center](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/fail2ban).

*excerpts*

> Let's test fail2ban to make sure it behaves the way we want it to. We'll do that by failing a few ssh logins.
>
> We'll use two machines: The server we want to protect and another machine to act as the attacker.
>
> - Attacking machine's IP: 123.45.67.89
> - The server's IP: 98.76.54.32
>
> To run the test, simply get on the attacking machine and try to ssh to your server five times. For example:
>
> ```
>    $ ssh fakeuser@98.76.54.32
> ```
>
> With the sixth try (assuming you have ssh's maxretry set to 5) your connection should time out if you try to ssh in again.

**NOTE:** This last sentence is what you're seeing!

Also you can setup `fail2ban` to send an email similar to this:

> If you have fail2ban set to send you email check to see if you got a message like this one:
>
> ```
>     From fail2ban@ITSecurity  Thu Jul 16 04:59:24 2009
>     Subject: [Fail2Ban] ssh: banned 123.45.67.89
>     Hi,
>
>     The ip 123.45.67.89 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after 5 attempts 
>     against ssh.
>
>     Here are more information about 123.45.67.89:
>
>     {whois info}
>
>     Lines containing IP:123.45.67.89 in /var/log/auth.log
>
>     Jul 16 04:59:16 example.com sshd[10390]: Failed password for root from 123.45.67.89 port 46023 ssh2
>     Jul 16 04:59:18 example.com sshd[10390]: Failed password for root from 123.45.67.89 port 46023 ssh2
>     Jul 16 04:59:20 example.com sshd[10390]: Failed password for root from 123.45.67.89 port 46023 ssh2
>     Jul 16 04:59:21 example.comsshd[10394]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 123.45.67.89.example.com [123.45.67.89] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
>     Jul 16 04:59:22 example.com sshd[10394]: Failed password for root from 123.45.67.89 port 46024 ssh2
>
>     Regards,
>
>     Fail2Ban
> ```

Probably the best indication though that `fail2ban` worked was the existence of a new `iptables` rule that's now blocking the attacking IP address.

For example:

```
iptables -L 

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  208-78-96-200.realinfosec.com  anywhere
```